# I should be able to just move the returning -1 outside the loop, but why do you think that is not possible?

Tags: c++

I thought to move the return -1 to outside the loop or by instead using an else block, but my apparently this is not possible. Why is this?

Here is the code:

```
int index_of(vector<string> &names, string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
    {
        if (to_lowercase(names[i]) == to_lowercase(name))
        {
            return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean that "it is not possible"?  Your code editor "cut and paste" should be working just fine.

Comment: It's much more correct to return -1 outside the loop. Otherwise you have a possible code path that does not set the function's return value. This will change the behavior of your function, but I would argue your function is currently broken because it doesn't do what it says on the tin. As a general observation, this is an inefficient way to do case-insensitive search. Not only do you repeatedly convert `name` to lowercase, but you likely have all kinds of copies happening and multiple searches repeat the conversion.

Comment: What happened when you moved `return -1;` outside the loop? Your current code shows it inside. Was there some type of problem? If so can you come up with a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem and show the output and expected output.

Comment: ***I should be able to just move the returning -1 outside the loop, but why do you think that is not possible?*** I don't see why you think it is not possible. At the moment I can't think of an example where it will break the code when moved outside in the proper place.

Comment: In case of ```name.size() == 0;```, program execution will not enter in for loop, and  you  have left nothing to return, that's why it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Since you passed the vector by reference, you should pass the string by constant reference.

Comment: The wording of the question is still not clear.  What is stopping you from moving the `return -1;` to outside the `for` loop?  Is it some tool you're using that is telling you "don't move that line"?  Is it something else?

Comment: It's not clear why you'd `return` every time inside a `for`. What you have is an overly ornate `if` statement.

Comment: This function is fundamentally wrong, too. If you're looking for the index of substring *a* inside of *b* you need two loops, not one. This just checks that the strings start with the same thing, but due to other defects, ends up comparing the strings in a case-insensitive manner instead.

Answer (score 2):

The function has to guarantee a return value. In your code, your `return -1;` depends completely on whether or not `names.size()` is greater than 0. If `names.size()` is less than or equal to 0, the thread won't even enter the for loop, meaning that your function will return effectively nothing.

Comment: Note: It doesn't return "nothing", it just exhibits undefined behaviour.